# How to use Nearest as a lookup function?

Tags: list-manipulation, data, nearest

I have `data1` and a target point `targetPts`, and want to find the closest point from the data. As you can see from below, the 29th point from the data is the closest point and thus the value of `data1[[29]]` is same as the desired value, which is `{0.67033, 0.84245}`.

```
data1 = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[7]; RandomReal[1, {30, 2}]];
targetPts = {0.68, 0.75};
data1[[29]]
Flatten@Nearest[data1, targetPts]
```

Now my problem changed a bit. I was given `data1data2` and I need to use it as the input. My desired output for this case is `{0.67033, 0.84245, 0.177696, 0.49873}`. The first 2 elements are used in the `Nearest` searching, while all 4 elements are the desired output. It just like a lookup function.

```
data2 = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[8]; RandomReal[1, {30, 2}]];
data1data2 = ArrayFlatten[{{data1, data2}}];
data1data2[[29]]
```

How can I get it done? Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
First @ Nearest[data1data2[[All, ;; 2]] -> "Index", targetPts]
```

> 29

```
data1data2[[First @ Nearest[data1data2[[All, ;; 2]] -> "Index", targetPts]]]
```

> {0.67033, 0.84245, 0.177696, 0.49873}

For versions prior to version 11.1 replace `"Index"` above with `Automatic` (thanks: Henrik Schumacher).

Comment: And in older versions (pre 11.1 or 11.2, `Automatic` instead of `"Index"` is the only way to get the indices.

Comment: Thanks for all of you. I recorded the time and noted that the `"Index"` approach is much faster than `First[Nearest[data1 -> data1data2, targetPts, 1]]` approach for large data size.

Answer (score 4):

You could pass a `Rule` to `Nearest`:

```
First[Nearest[data1 -> data1data2, targetPts, 1]]
```

> {0.67032993, 0.84245042, 0.17769644, 0.49872995}